# Count within a count, in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I am the following structure

```
class Vegetable(models.Model):
    vegetable_name = models.Chafield(max_legnth = 100)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    buyer_name = models.Chafield(max_legnth = 100)

Class Holding(models.Model):
    vegetable = models.ForeignKey(Vegetable)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
```

I want to get the count of which buyer holds a particular vegetable and also the total number of units of that particular vegetable held.Of course I can use filters and annotations, but they give me a dictionary.For example I can use

```
Holding.objects.filter(vegetable__pk='223').values('buyer').annotate(tcount=Count('buyer'))
```

(Just an example )

This gives me the following list as answer:

```
[{'buyer': '111', 'tcount': 3}, {'buyer': u'112', 'tcount': 4}, {'buyer': u'113', 'tcount': 3}]
```

now the total holding or the vegetable is  3 + 4 + 3 = 10

I will have to go through additional computation of iterating through the dictionaries and retrieving the values for count and adding them.Also I dont want to make an additional query, just to get the holding of the vegetable with pk = '223'. Can I somehow get all this information only with one ORM query and also not perform any iterative computation.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `the count of which buyer holds a particular vegetable` and `the total number of units of that particular vegetable held`. Can you provide some example data and what is the expected result?

Comment: for example if I filter with "tomato", I get the following result:

Comment: that's not an example. data + result means: show us your initial data and then your expected result

Comment: Sorry that was posted incomplete:

For example, let us take an example pf 'tomato'.If I filter with 'tomato' I get the following result, using the above query:
[{'buyer': '111', 'tcount': 3}, {'buyer': u'112', 'tcount': 4}, {'buyer': u'113', 'tcount': 3}] (again just an example )

Comment: Hey apologies for the incomplete question. I have completed it.

Comment: got it, you want to have two different aggregations in one query. not sure how to do it though.

Comment: i think you might need to do this in two queries. yours and the answer of Seppo Erviälä.

Answer (score 1):

To get the total number of particular vegetable across all buyers you can:

```
Vegetable.objects.filter(vegetable_name="Carrot").count()
```

Comment: but this would mean that I put two ORM queries.One for getting the count of the holdings and one for the total count.I want to get it done in one ORM query, if possible

Comment: I do not know how to make it in one ORM query. I would do it with two and add caches if it makes the service slow.

Comment: Also is there any plug in or app which can achieve this ?